# Mongo DB c# query ALL element's property in nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I'm trying to get a filter with a certain condition to get documents that have an inner array of documents that have a property:

```
public class MyObject {
    public List<InnerObject> InnerObjects {get;set;}
}

public class InnerObject {
    public bool Accepted {get;set;}
}
```

Now I want to query for all `MyObjects` that have **ALL** inner objects with **Accepted** set to a certain value, in this case to **FALSE**. I built the filter:

```
filter = Builders<MyObject>.Filter.ElemMatch(
                                c => c.InnerObjects,
                                Builders<InnerObject>.Filter.Eq(c => c.Accepted, false));
```

Which does not work because as it will also return MyObjects with any instance of InnerObject set to true as well, which I could understand. The thing is I don't find any operator that does what I want to achieve. Note that I wanted to also have a filter with at least an InnerObject with Accept to certain value (in fact the filter from above would achieve that), so my only problem is to get the object will **ALL** instances of `InnerObject.Accepted` set to either **TRUE** or **FALSE**.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do the reverse of it to achieve. Please translate the query into C# syntax.

```
db.collection.find({
  "InnerObject.Accepted": {
    $not: {
      $eq: true
    }
  }
})
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/SgEpt96uxdb

Following C# syntax (please follow best practices and good OO principles)

```
        var notAccepted = Builders<InnerObject>.Filter.Not(
            Builders<InnerObject>.Filter.Eq(u => u.Accepted, false)
        );
        
        IMongoCollection<MyObject> myobjectsCollection = null;
        myobjectsCollection.Find(Builders<MyObject>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.InnerObjects, notAccepted));
```

Comment: Would it be that query equivalent to filter = Builders<MyObject>.Filter.ElemMatch(
                                c => c.InnerObjects,
                                Builders<InnerObject>.Filter.Ne(c => c.Accepted, true)); ?? Because that's what I have and it does not seem to be working

Comment: No. You are using Ne, what you need is Not.

Comment: I see. Will try that thanks!

Comment: Syntax will be similar to Builders<InnerObject>.Filter.Not(
                Builders<InnerObject>.Filter.Eq(u => u.Accepted, false)
            ). But I am can't remember the syntax to bring it together with MyObject

Comment: I guess that would be an ElemMatch to operate within the InnerObject array?

Comment: I have added C# example as well, test it out.

Comment: Exactly that, many thanks!